# UITableView inside a UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello I want to create a `UITableviewCell` like this.

[image]

There can be 1 or more attached documents.How can I show attached documents if there are more than 1 documents.

Can I use a `A UITableview` inside the `UITableViewCell`? If so how? What is the best way that I can achieve this?

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vertical scrolling inside a UITableViewCell would be kind of strange and complicated because you can also scroll in the normal table view. Wouldn´t it be a better solution for you to set the height of the cell depending on the number of attached items. One pseudo example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return cell.attachedItems.count * 50
}
```

Then a cell with more attached items would be bigger and you could keep the normal table view scrolling flow.